# Shotwell tags - difference between 'Keywords' and 'Subject'

Tags: shotwell, exif

When I add tags to a photo via Shotwell and then look at all of the exif data with exiftool I see that the Shotwell tags are stored under two different exif tag names - 'Keywords' and 'Subject'. I'm wondering what the difference is between these two? Is it in the different ways that other photo manager programs interpret tags?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question. 'Subject' is an XMP tag and 'Keywords' is an IPTC tag. Curious that there is no actual EXIF tag.